# Skipping test case execution using testng.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide, testng.xml

In my project, we have developed the structure such as we can run the individual test cases from the test files where as for a complete BVT, we have to run the same cases using testng xml that too in the proper sequence(skipping the current test, if previous test fails).

However when we tried to run the scenario with this approach, we are either able to run all the scenario(not able to skip the tests and all of them failing if first fails) or none of them runs at all.

Please have a look at the below code snippet similar to my project code and let me know if I am missing something here.

**First Test :**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; /** * Hello world! * */
public class App {
 @Test(groups = "FirstGroup") public void testCase1() {
  boolean x = true;
  System.out.println("Test Case 1");
  Assert.assertEquals(x, true);
 }
}
```

**Second Test :**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class App2 {
 @Test(groups = "SecondGroup") public void testCase2() {
  boolean x = true;
  System.out.println("Test Case 2");
  Assert.assertEquals(x, false);
 }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="softwaretestingmaterial">
    <test name="testngTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="Project.Test.Test.App" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="testngTest2">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Project.Test.Test.App" />
                <include name="Project.Test.Test.App2" />
            </run>
            <dependencies>
                <group name="SecondGroup" depends-on="FirstGroup"></group>
            </dependencies>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="Project.Test.Test.App2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Chetan, please edit your question and include the TestNG version that you are using. Also please try to use the latest version of TestNG `7.0.0-beta7` as of today and see if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try specifying these dependencies as annotations shown as below, instead of specifying them in the TestNg.xml file.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class App2 {
 **@Test(groups = "SecondGroup", dependsOnMethods = { "testCase1" })** 
public void testCase2() {
  boolean x = true;
  System.out.println("Test Case 2");
  Assert.assertEquals(x, false);
 }
}
```

Updated Answer:
Yeah you are right about that.
It seems that there is no easy way to achieve this. However, I did some reading and found this:
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng

You can couple this mechanism with ITestListener to skip subsequent tests if priority tests fails. Although I am not very certain how that will work but a Logic for the same can be designed.

Your Last option would be to use an ITestListener in combination with an Excel Sheet that stores the Pass/Fail status of your Priority test and skips tests accordingly

Comment: Thanks Arjun, But doing this would make the second test  **Hard Dependednt** on first which means I wont be able to run the second test independently.

Comment: Yeah you are right about that.
It seems that there is no easy way to achieve this. However, I did some reading and found this:
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng